# How to install phpmyadmin on Webmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, webmin

I am trying to install **phpmyadmin** on **webmin** as webmin itself does not provide a very friendly Mysql administration, therefor i decided to install phpmyadmin on it.

I tried to install **PHPMYADMIN** as a module, but didnt work thru **Virtualmin**.

What I am doing right now is, open command shell within webmine and created a phpmyadmin folder inside etc/ so now it looks like etc/phpmyadmin/ I used wget command to get the phpmyadmin package, it worked, but the only problem now is i cant unzip it.. I am using the command unzip and the package name of phpmyamin but it says this:

```
Archive: phpMyAdmin-4.0.5-all-languages.zip?r=http:%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fdirectory%2Fos:windows%2Ffreshness:recently-updated%2F?q=phpmyadmin
replace phpMyAdmin-4.0.5-all-languages/ChangeLog? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
(EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
```

1 archive had warnings but no fatal errors.

and when i write ls command within **phpmyadmin** it shows like this:

> ls
>   phpMyAdmin-4.0.5-all-languages
>   phpMyAdmin-4.0.5-all-languages.zip?r=http:%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fdirectory%2Fos:windows%2Ffreshness:recently-updated%2F?q=phpmyadmin

What I am doing wrong???
how can i just unzip one of this zip files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you actually unzip the files, just type:
cd phpMyAdmin-4.0.5-all-languages
ls

then you should see the files... You do not need to install phpmyadmin, then just open it in your browser and configure it...

and well you don want to unzip it inside /etc, you need to have it in your webserver directory or somewhere else (like /opt) and then configure the webserver...

Also you need to have installed php... so just look after your apache server or which one you have, so you know where to extract your phpmyadmin...

**EDIT:**
if you are using apache, then look after Documentroot directory http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ApacheWebserver

If you unzip phpmyadmin there, then you will be able to run it something like
    `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`   .... where localhost is address of your server

Comment: First of all, why cant i install it on etc directory?

I saw that opt directory is empty, can u be more specifik regarding installing php?

Comment: Because the /etc is not for that, it is for configuration files... look at that link [http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/) I am not sure what os you are running on but on debian or ubuntu it is sudo apt-get install php5

Comment: But not sure if you need to do this.... look at [http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?search=phpmyadmin](http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?search=phpmyadmin) here you can download phpmyadmin module for webmin....

Comment: its debian, i tried that command and it is already php the newest versionm,i have also already downloaded that module but when i try to install it, it says phpmyadmin is not for webmine, it is for usermin... and in usermin when i log in i dont see any option to install phpmyadmin module

Comment: Try to look inside: 
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ls

You should find something like default so type in terminal cat default And then look in output for DocumentRoot 

But still it says that in usermin after installing that module you should find link to the phpmyadmin...